Making header responsive in Angular
I have the below code (in Angular 18):
<header>

<!-- Other header code above here -->

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-9 text-end">
                <div class="menu-icon" (click)="openMenu()">
                    <i class="{{menu_icon}}"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="desktop_menu" [class.mobile_menu]="menuValue">
                    <ul> 
                        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li  *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li  *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout(); closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
</div>
</header>

I tried to make it mobile responsive by putting the below ts functions:
openMenu(){
    this.menuValue =! this.menuValue ;
    this.menu_icon = this.menuValue ? 'bi bi-x' : 'bi bi-list';
  }
  closeMenu() {
    this.menuValue = false;
    this.menu_icon = 'bi bi-list';
  }

But its not working for small screens. I think there might be a problem in CSS:
header {
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* Transparent background */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px); /* Optional: add blur effect for better text readability */
}
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
.desktop_menu {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
.desktop_menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.desktop_menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white; /* Change to white for readability */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 26px;
}
.desktop_menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline from links */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Set link color to white for readability */
}
.desktop_menu ul li a:hover {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(18, 6, 241);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and  (max-width: 900px) {
.desktop_menu {
    position: fixed !important;
    right: -280px;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    top: 64px;
    background: rgb(241, 240, 240); /* Light blue semi-transparent background */
    width: 280px;
    height: -400px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .desktop_menu.open {
    background: lightblue; /* Light blue background when menu is open */
  }
  .desktop_menu ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 26px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 1005;
  }
  .mobile_menu {
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
}

I am sorry if some parts of the code looks unruly or redundant. This is my first Angular project and I am really confused.
I want the add the button functionality for all those "Home", "About", etc. in small screen size and to make it responsive.
